# Efficient Random Texture Sampling in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, glsl, textures, shader

Is there any efficient way to fetch texture data in a random way? That is, I'd like to use a texture as a look-up table and I need random access to its elements. Therefore I'd be sampling it in a random fashion. Is it a completely lost cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random access is a basic feature of GLSL. E.g.

```
vec2 someLocation = ... whatever you like ...;
vec4 sampledColour = texture2D(sampler, someLocation);
```

Depending on your hardware, it may cost more to read a texture if you've calculated the sample locations directly in the pixel shader rather than out in the vertex shader and allowed them to be interpolated automatically as a varying, but that's just an immutable hardware cost relating to the decreased predictability of what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, random access is quite possible, I'm only troubled with the fact that from what I've read random access with GPUs is far more of a problem than with CPUs so I wondered if there was a generic way to minimize the penalty of random access.

Comment: I'm not sure what your platform is, but my understanding of the trend is that this used to matter a lot more than it does now (with the caveat that mobile phone-type devices are at an earlier point on the curve), because it's to do with what the GPU can obviously and easily do in parallel for multiple fragments versus what it has to do individually for every single one. However, the push to GPGPU has made everyone generalise a bit more, to get a bit more CPU like in terms of strategies for guessing smart access patterns. So you may get a performance hit but it shouldn't be much to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

You could always pass another texture to the shader containing random values and sample from that. That will give you the same random value for each texture coordinate but if you dont want that you can always multiply the coordinate by a uniform seed that you updated each frame.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't mean that. I'm not interested in generating random values. What I meant is that I'm most likely to be accessing the texture data in a random way rather than in a serialized fashion.